# How to retrieve the source code from a jnlp file

Tags: java, swing, jnlp

I have downloaded a few `jnlp` files from the oracle tutorials in swing available on their website which they give as examples. While they run run but is there also any way that I can retrieve the source code from them? It would really help me to understand their examples better.

Thanx in advance!!

Comment: open jnlp with text editor, you'll see jar files, get them by browser, but you can't get source code from JNLP AFAIK.

Comment: If your downloaded examples from the Oracle tutorial site, they typically provide source links separately (normally at the end of the page)

Comment: @VahidFarahmand what do you mean by "get them by browser"? The text editor shows an jnlp tab `<jnlp>..</jnlp>` which further contains the information and resources tab. They also mention a jar file of the same name as the jnlp file.

Comment: that jar file is the actual program. You can get that jar file by browser, but that's also a compiled one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given a `.jnlp` file from [*The Java Tutorials*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), focus on two [*Java Web Start*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) attributes:

```
codebase="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6"
main-class="components.ColorChooserDemo"
```

And search for the `main-class` name on the `codebase` site, for example

```
http://www.google.com/#q=site:oracle.com+ColorChooserDemo
```

Voilà, [first hit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html)!

Bonus feature: most example sections have the HTML `name`, [`eg`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#eg).